# Control not drawn on panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to add a control to my Panel. At mouseDown on the panel the point is saved and at mouseUp the point is saved. But at panel mouseUp nothing is drawn. How to solve it?

Ellipse class:

```
class Ellipse : Control
{    

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Ellipse(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        setY(y);
        setX(x);
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
    }

    public int getX() { return x;}
    public int getY() { return y; }
    public int getWidth() { return width; }
    public int getHeight() { return height; }
    public void setX(int newx) { x = newx; }
    public void setY(int newy) { y = newy; }
    public void setWidth(int newwidth) { width = newwidth; }
    public void setHeight(int newheight) { height = newheight; }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        // Call methods of the System.Drawing.Graphics object.
        // Declare and instantiate a new pen.
        System.Drawing.Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Aqua);

        // Draw an aqua rectangle in the rectangle represented by the control.
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black,x,y,width,height);
    }    
}
```

Form1 class

```
private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = true;
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
    }

private void panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        draw = false;
        xe = e.X;
        ye = e.Y;

        Item item; 
        Enum.TryParse<Item>(menuComboBoxShape.ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), out item);

        switch (item)
        {

            case Item.Pencil:
                using (Graphics g = panel.CreateGraphics())
                    using (var pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black))     //Create the pen used to draw the line (using statement makes sure the pen is disposed)
                    {
                        g.DrawLine(pen,new Point(x, y), new Point(xe, ye));
                    }
                break;
            case Item.Rectangle:
                break;
            case Item.Ellipse:
                Ellipse el = new Ellipse(x,y,xe-x,ye-y);
                panel.Controls.Add(el);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried debugging? What is the value of mDown on `mouseDown` event?

Comment: I put a breakpoint on `mDown = e.Location;` but it's not reached

Comment: What is panel? Can you share relevant code?

Comment: Is `KeyPreview` property on form set to `true`?

Comment: @Abhishek panel is just a `Panel`. I added the `MouseUp` of the panel

Comment: @HariPrasad I tried `KeyPreview` true, it was on false but no diffrence.

Comment: You need to *add* the control to the panel, not just manually paint it over. Just do e.g. `panel.Controls.Add(new Ellipse())`. How could the mouse events fire when you don't have the controls anywhere? As far as the UI is concerned, they don't exist. You're just calling a `Paint` method and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting your `Ellipse` class from Control, but in fact you're not using it as a control - you're not adding it in `Controls` collection of form, so in fact it is invisible, inactive and not receiving any events from form.

Also painting the control from outer code looks like a bad design. Control should paint itself, and you should set it bounds from outer code.

Here is snippet to drive you to the right way:

```
class Ellipse : Control
{
    Point mDown { get; set; }

    public Ellipse()
    {
        MouseDown += shape_MouseDown;
        MouseMove += shape_MouseMove;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, this.Bounds);
    }

    private void shape_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = e.Location;
    }

    private void shape_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Location = new Point(e.X + Left - mDown.X, e.Y + Top - mDown.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the form you should create it like:

```
el = new Ellipse();
el.Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
Controls.Add(el);
```

**Update**

Based on your updated code, I can see a couple of issues:

1. You actually don't need `x, y, width, height` properties of your `Ellipse` class and according getter/setter methods, since it's `Control`, and it has its own `Location` and `Width`, `Height` public properties.
2. You are drawing your ellipse incorrectly. Assuming it should fill all the area, painting should be `e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black,0,0,Width,Height)` (here I assuming using `Control.Width` instead of your `width` and so on). Otherwise you're additionally shifting your painted ellipse.
3. Code in `panel_MouseUp` concerning ellipse creation should be something like

```
var el = new Ellipse();
panel.Controls.Add(el);
el.Location = new Point(x, y);
el.Width = (xe - x);
el.Height = (ye - y);
```

Or, if it should be one single ellipse (right now you're creating new one each time) - create this one outside of mouseUp handler and inside of handler just change it's size and location.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how should my `Shape` class look like?

Comment: @Sybren all I see in your `Shape` class - is  `Paint`method. If we following the concept "control should paint itself, and not from outer code" - this mehod is not needed. If you need something more in Shape - it's up to you. If nothing more in Shape - probably it is not needed at all and you can inherit ellipse from `Control` directly.

Comment: I use your code now but I changed this `Controls.Add(el);` into this `panel.Controls.Add(el);` because I want to add to the `panel`. This is the result: http://gyazo.com/5cc6fac8473200f34c26849381637af4 . Any ideas?

Comment: @Sybren it's hard to say very much without seeing youк changed code. I hope you haven't "blindly" copied my code since it is some abstract snippet (for example, it has fixed rectengle to draw ellipse in and so on). Also note - you need to create your ellipse outside of `panel_MouseUp` and in your mouseup handler you should only update its location (if I have understood correctly what do you trying to do).

Comment: I want to draw at MouseUp look at the modified code please.

Comment: Thank you very much, based on your updated answer I managed to get it working.